# Several Tabs clicked (URL changed with hashes) then Browser-Back-Button one site Back?

Tags: jquery, html, browser, tabs

I've a site with several Tabs on it. If I click on a Tab the URL changes in the way of:

```
www.example.com/site1.html#tab-2
www.example.com/site1.html#tab-5
```

So If I've clicked two tabs (URL changes two times) and then clicking on the browser-history-back-button, then the browser first go through all the URL-changes before I finally come to the site before the site I am seeing.

How to avoid that? If I am clicking on the browser-history-back-butten I want to jump to the last page regardless how many Tabs I clicked before (and how many times the URL changes this way)

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you making a server request when you click on the tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specific HTML or javascript from your use case, it is hard to narrow in on the best approach. That said, there are really three important tools in your toolkit when dealing with history state and hashes.

**Preventing the change**

You can also avoid the whole problem by using `event.preventDefault();` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)) in the handler code for your tabs, something like this:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

When the user clicks the tab, you immediately call `preventDefault` -- this will stop the default action from continuing. In this case, you're preventing the default behavior of a link (presumably) changing the URL of the document. The `...` indicates your existing code for handling the tab click action.

All told (and again without seeing your use case), this is probably the "best" approach; at least, it is easier.

**Detecting the change**

You can use the `onhashchange` event of the `window` object ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange), note limited browser support) to detect changes to the hash.

The `onpopstate` event of the `window` object can be used in a similar way ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate)), but this is a subtly different and may be more appropriate depending on how you're implementing the "tabs", and whether you need to monitor other changes to the history state.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
   console.log('hash change', e);  
});

$(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
    console.log('popstate', e);
});
```

See both in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/m7qV9/1/ (**be sure to have your console open**)

With either of these approaches, you would use the `history` object ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)) to manage replacing or adding to the history, depending on the need.

**One approach: replacement**

Here's a small sample using `history.replaceState`. This approach allows you to keep the active tab's identifier in the URL so the user can get back to where they were through their history, but you don't clutter up their history record with each changed tab. `http://www.mySite.com/#tab2`, for example, would open tab #2 when the page loaded, but if the user switched to tab 1, went to another page, then came back, tab #1 would be active.

Keep in mind, this is mockup of the concept. I don't know what your existing HTML and javascript look like, so I'm only demonstrating an approach, not creating a direct solution for your specific implementation.

```
$('.tab').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var whichtab = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
   updateTab(whichtab, $(this).parent());
   return false;
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.hash.length > 0)
        updateTab(document.location.hash);
});
var updateTab = function (tab, parent) {
    if (!parent)
        parent = document;
    if (parent.find('.tab[href='+tab+']').length < 1)
        return;
    parent.find('.tab[href='+tab+']').addClass('active');
    parent.find('.tabContent-'+tab.replace('#', '')).addClass('active');
    window.history.replaceState({}, '', tab);
    return true;    
};
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Qegc/

Without a better idea of what javascript and HTML you're using, it is hard to be precise. Hope this helps.

**Documentation**

- `event.preventDefault` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault
- `window.onhashchange` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange
- `window.onpopstate` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate
- *Manipulating the browser history* on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score -2):

may be you can use 'javascript:void(0)' in the href attribute of your anchor tag.

like this

```
</`<a href = 'javascript:void(0)'>Tab-2</a>`
```